# Scrapy encoding nested dict params

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, scrapy

I want to send a request which has params in nested dict.

```
params = {
  'apiKey': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'facetInclusion': 'All',
  'filter': '{"facetFilter": {"andClauses": [{"value": "WEBCAT_1_2_1", "type": "CategoryCode", "negate": false}], "orClauses": []}, "numericalFilter": [], "filteringFacetFilter": {"andClauses": []}}',
  'pageNumber': 0,
  'pageSize': 48,
  'productRepresentation': 'ExplicitRepresentation'....}
```

I want to send it via Scrapy request but I get 422 and error code that something is wrong with params

```
yield scrapy.Request(url=self.url, cb_kwargs=params, callback=self.parse, headers=self.headers)
```

However when I try to send the same request with `requests` it goes okay

```
response = requests.get(url=self.url, headers=self.headers, params=params)
```

I tried all different forms of encoding and dumping the url + params but I always get 422 form Scrapy. Any idea where can be the problem? Many thanks

Comment: a [scrapy.Request](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) is not the same thing as a the request library.  Instead of trying a combination of things that work for a completely separate library, it would be smarter and faster to just read the scrapy documentation.

Comment: I've read the docs and I am aware of the differences. However nothing worked for me to get successful response which I was able to get with requests.

Comment: Read superusers answer... that is the correct way

Answer (score 1):

[cb_kwargs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.cb_kwargs) is a dictionary that will be passed the request’s callback.

[body](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.body) is the request's body.

```py
import json

yield scrapy.Request(url=self.url, body=json.dumps(params), callback=self.parse, headers=self.headers)
```

**EDIT**:

I misunderstood your question. This is what you want:

```py
import urllib.parse
url_params = '?' + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)

yield scrapy.Request(url=self.url+urlparams, callback=self.parse, headers=self.headers)
```

Where `url` is something like `www.url.com/products/search`.

Comment: Hi, it's not working unfortunately. Are you sure `body` in scrapy.Request has the same functionality as `params` in requests. In my case params are added behind `www.url.com/api?params`. It might be done by encoding in my opinion, but all I tried did not work out. 
params encoded example `/products/search?apiKey=xxxxxxx-xxxx-43ce-9139-570b80ad54fb&facetInclusion=All&filter=%7B%22facetFilter%22%3A+%7B%22andClauses%22%3A+%5B%7B%22value%22%3A+%22WEBCAT_1_2_1%22%2C+%22type%22%3A+%22CategoryCode%22%2C+%22negate%22%3A+false%7D%5D%2C+%22orC`

Comment: @PetrSevcik, See the edit, please update me if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thank you @SuperUser, I've tried it and it didn't work, but then I've found that if I encode it via `requests` params and `urllib.parse.urlencode(params)` it works somehow differently. As the params body is quite big and contains many dict, lists and strings, which are like nested dict it is probably crashing on some spaces. Anyhow I've solved it by taking URL string with params which works and replace the parts I needed by simle `url_with_params.replace("old_param", "new_param")` . It`s quite dirty solution but works